# C# remove all but two least significant bits of color

Tags: c#, math, colors

On [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Digital_steganography) page, see the picture of the tree and its caption. I'm planning on implementing a plugin for [Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net/) to do just that... but I'm not sure how.

I'm already looping through every pixel (for those wondering, the Paint.NET API makes this efficient) as a `ColorBgra` (Can be converted to `System.Drawing.Color`), but now I need to modify the pixel to remove "all but the two least significant bits of each color."

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each component (R, G, B, A) you need to mask off the unwanted bits, as in:

```
colour.R &= 3;
colour.G &= 3;
colour.B &= 3;
colour.A &= 3;
```

Comment: Works great! Although... could you perhaps provide a little more explanation on what the 3 signifies... and how I would remove other bits?

Comment: The 3 is the sum of the two least significant bits: 0x00000011 == 3

Comment: To remove other bits you can simply switch them on or off: Bit 7 is 0x01000000, Bit 3 is 0x00000100, Bit 1,3,5,7 is 0x01010101

Comment: careful; in C# 0x... signifies hexadecimal, where 3 == 0x03 (and 15 == 0x0F etc.)

Comment: If you need to do this with a `System.Drawing.Color` object at some point in time, you'll need to do `Color NewColor = Color.FromArgb(baseColor.A & 3,baseColor.R & 3,baseColor.G & 3,baseColor.B & 3);`, since the A, R, G and B are readonly properties here.